# How to debug via npm with a module CLI?

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code

I use this npm scripts from `package.json` file :

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup --config",
    "build-debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=5858 rollup --config"
}
```

Rollup is the CLI of [rollup.js library](https://rollupjs.org) installed locally and so available in `node_modules/.bin`

When i execute`npm run build` it work perfectly.
Now i want to execute this command with the VSCode debugger.

So i created the `launch.json` file with this configuration:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Build",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "windows": {
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd"
        },
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run",
            "build-debug"
        ],
        "port": 5858
    }
]
```

But the debugger failed

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
>   npm.cmd run build-debug
>   Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/e0210d85-ee1d-4895-a67f-a23581725b31
>   Debugger attached.
>   module.js:487
>       throw err;
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'd:\Temp\myproject\rollup'

if i use the rollup path, i have a syntaxerror :

```
"scripts": {
    "build-debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=5858 node_modules/.bin/rollup --config"
}
```

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
>   npm.cmd run build-debug
>   Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/c43fe903-b54d-4804-84d2-37d3c98b40e2
>   Debugger attached.
>   d:\Temp\myproject\node_modules\.bin\rollup:2
>   basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")
>
> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Here vscode launches node in debug running rollup with whatever configuration you have in your working dir:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/rollup/bin/rollup",
        "args": [
            "-c"
        ]
    }
]
```